# Python pandas seed for random generator

Tags: python, pandas, random, seed

I have a small question re: `np.random.seed(seed=x)`
I have a df `SEED = 1` column of seed numbers
I would like to generate random number after choosing a seed from my df `SEED`
For example in the first simulation I'll use seed no 100 of the df `SEED` and in the next simulation, I want to use seed no 200 of the `SEED` df.
I've been trying out things , but to no avail.
Any hints for me?
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need loop by values of column `SEED` and set `np.random.seed(x)`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SEED':[100,200,500]})
print (df)
   SEED
0   100
1   200
2   500

for i, x in df['SEED'].items():
    print (x)
    np.random.seed(x)
    #some random function
    a = np.random.randint(10, size=5)
    print (a)

100
[8 8 3 7 7]
200
[9 0 4 7 9]
500
[7 1 1 8 7]
```

---

If need generate random value from list:

```
L = [100,200,500]
a = np.random.choice(L, size=1)[0]
np.random.seed(a)
print (a)
500
```

Comment: in fact in the example you have, the first time round I would need the seed at index postion 0. I don't really need a loop ; I just want to read the seed from a file by it's row and col number (1 col only)

Comment: Sorry, so i dont understand. `I have a df SEED = 1 column of seed numbers`. Can you explain more?

Comment: my fault for not being clear: I'll try again: instead of giving an integer to num.random.seed(), I want to tell it to go and fetch the integer in the first row of the SEED df. And in an adjacent simulation, I'll tell it to get the second row of the SEED df,,,

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. You need generate values and write them to column? Sorry. I understand your question get int number from column `SEED` and use it in function `np.random.seed(x)`. Am I wrong?

Comment: say I want to do 1 simulation only but instead of giving np.random.seed() an integer, I want to give it the 101th integer of a list of seeds I already have.  Next year, when I do the simulation again, I may want to use the 93th interger instead.  Ok? but I don't want to write the integer in the code every time. I would like to give Python the row number in the seed list and let python go get the integer and use it in np.random.seed(). Is that clearer?

Comment: Ok, but I miss column `SEED` in dataframe. Do you need random generate number from list to `np.random.seed(x)` ?

Comment: the SEED dataframe is my collection of random interger - maybe it's not the right format for it. I created the SEED df from a csv file of 100000 random number I have. So I want in my simulation to use the row 101 from the dataframe SEED as seed to use in np.random.seed()

Comment: Ok, then use `df.loc[101, 'SEED']`.

Comment: ah ah when I test s = SEED.loc[2,'seed'] I do get s = 6264338327 which is the interger indexed at index= 2. Good. But when I plug this into num.random.seed(SEED.loc[2,'seed']) it does not work and says that the seed must be an interger between 0 and ...

Comment: I appreciate your patience @jezrael

Comment: I am surprised too ;) But I think you are close. If check `Random seed used to initialize the pseudo-random number generator. Can be any integer between 0 and 2**32 - 1` in [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState) I think you have to large integer.

Comment: you may be right there... I directly plugged with the same number and got the same negative answer...

Comment: Yes, need generate smaller ints.

Comment: perfect- it works! many thanks for the help- really appreciated

Comment: Glad can help ;) Thank you for patience too ;)

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to pick an value from a dataframe of seeds. Using your SEED dataframe, you just pick an offset (INDEX) into the SEED dataframe and you will get the value. Use that value as the random seed generator.

```
# What is my index to use this year?
INDEX = 1

df = pd.DataFrame({'SEED':[100,200,500]})

seed = (df["SEED"].iloc[INDEX]).item()

random.seed(seed)
```

Comment: This answer could do with some explanation rather than just being code-only.

Comment: What is `.item()` for in this code? I don't think it's needed.

Comment: It is needed as the way I wrote it. Leaving off .item() on the above code is not going to work. Without it you will get a numpy64 type which is not valid as input to random.seed()